# application crashes -= XMPP for iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, xmpp, xmppframework

I am creating chat application and I am using the XMPP code ,

Here is the application logs shows the crash , please help me out if any one knows the solutions

Terminating app due to uncaught exception

'NSInvalidArgumentException',

reason: '-[XMPPvCardCoreDataStorage clearvCardTempForJID:xmppStream:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x29bbe0'

**Here is the Stack**

Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x3172464f __exceptionPreprocess + 114

1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x3523fc5d objc_exception_throw + 24

```
2   CoreFoundation                      0x317281bf -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 102
3   CoreFoundation                      0x317278ad -[NSObject(NSObject) forwardInvocation:] + 36
4   CoreFoundation                      0x3172768d ___forwarding___ + 576
5   CoreFoundation                      0x3169e180 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 48
6   iPhoneXMPP                          0x0003681d -[XMPPvCardAvatarModule xmppStreamWillConnect:] + 132
7   CoreFoundation                      0x317277a4 __invoking___ + 68
8   CoreFoundation                      0x3169f43d -[NSInvocation invoke] + 108
9   CoreFoundation                      0x3169f0d9 -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 36
10  iPhoneXMPP                          0x0002a383 __42-[GCDMulticastDelegate forwardInvocation:]_block_invoke_0 + 70
11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x3600a8e7 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10
12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x36005ec1 _dispatch_queue_drain + 240
13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x36006033 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 78
14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x360055f1 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 192
15  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3640b591 _pthread_wqthread + 264
16  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3640bbc4 _init_cpu_capabilities + 4294967295
```

)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you are calling the following method,

```
- (void)clearvCardTempForJID:(XMPPJID *)jid  xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)stream
```

it should be called with two arguments ie JabberId and XmppStream object.You may set those thing wrongly.

```
[XMPPvCardCoreDataStorage clearvCardTempForJID:urNeededJid:xmppStream];
```

Comment: No - As with V3 of XMPP - this clearvCard method is shifted to XMPPvCardAvatarModule , So I don't think that this method will work .